# How to prevent a React component from unmounting when url path is matched using react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm currently struggling using React and its library react-router-dom.

To simplify:

I've this in my App component:

```
const App = () => {

  return (
    <Router>
      <Layout>
        <Switch>
           // <Other Routes />
          <Route path='/product/:id' component={ProductScreen} />
          // <Other Routes />
        </Switch>
      </Layout>
    </Router>
  )
}
```

The `<ProductScreen />` (single product view) is wrapped like this:
[image]

The `<ProductNav />` component embeds two links from react-router-dom. It also includes the required logic to reach previous or next product. Like so for instance:

```
<Link 
   className='prev'
   to={`/product/${currentIndex - 1 < 0 ? ids[lastIndex] : ids[currentIndex - 1]}`}
>
   Previous
</Link>
```

It's working but I'm not satisfied with that approach because the `<ProductScreen />` unmounts each time I click 'previous' or 'next' and this leads to some unaesthetic things on the page. **I would like to prevent it from unmounting** in order to have this instead:

[image]

I tried many things, read the doc but I'm quite stuck right now. If anyone has any idea of how to achieve that I would be glad to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Route nested Route as following:

```
<Header />
<Main>
<Route path="/products" component={Product> />
</Main>
<Footer />
```

on page Product

```
const {url} = useRouteMatch();
render() {
    <>
       <Navbar />
       <Route path=`${url}/:id` component={ProductDetail} />
    </>

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I gave a try to your solution but this isn't working. When I click on prev or next, the ```<ProductScreen />``` component still unmounts. I was expecting just to have the ```<ProductDetail />``` to unmount...

Comment: I was doing it multiple times and it works. when you change id on /products/id, only component ProductDetail is reloaded.

Comment: did you log something on componentWillUnmount lifecycle?

Comment: In fact it seems working now... Don't know what I was messing up before. Thank you. For anyone having the same troubles I would recommend to check that link: https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting